# squid cache is not working

Tags: proxy, cache, squid

I have configured squid for anonymous search and cache proxy. Initially it was working well, after two weeks it becomes slow(loading web page become slow) then again I had to looked into squid. I saw there was updated standard version of squid then I did update squid from 3.1.19 to 3.3.4. Now squid is running all the traffic from our network going through squid proxy server only. I see again internet connection is slow then I enabled cache feature in squid as

```
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid3 10240 32 512
cache_mem 256 MB
```

I checked the size of cache as

```
du -sh /var/cache/squid3
```

output:

> 65 M

I checked the size of cache again after one day I see same `65 M`, squid didn't cache anything at all. what would be the problem? should I configure anything else.

And the internet connection is very slow.

Comment: There's no "utf" option for cache_dir. Do you mean "ufs"?

Comment: yes it is "ufs", my bad.

Comment: Is there anything in the logfiles? Common problems are trivial, such as incorrect permissions.